# Dynamically adding class methods to a class

Tags: python, metaprogramming, class-method

I have the following snippet:

```
FEED_TYPES = [
    ('fan_mail',     'Fan Mail'),
    ('review',       'Review'),
    ('tip',          'Tip'),
    ('fan_user',     'Fan User'),
    ('fan_song',     'Fan Song'),
    ('fan_album',    'Fan Album'),
    ('played_song',  'Played Song'),
    ('played_album', 'Played Album'),
    ('played_radio', 'Played Radio'),
    ('new_event',    'New Event'),
]

class Feed:
    @classmethod
    def do_create(cls, **kwargs):
        print kwargs

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, type, **kwargs):
        kwargs['feed_type'] = type
        cls.do_create(**kwargs)

for type_tuple in FEED_TYPES:
    type, name = type_tuple

    def notify(self, **kwargs):
        print "notifying %s" % type
        self.create(type, **kwargs)

    notify.__name__ = "notify_%s" % type
    setattr(Feed, notify.__name__, classmethod(notify))

Feed.create("FanMail", to_profile="Gerson", from_profile="Felipe")
Feed.notify_fan_mail(to_profile="Gerson2", from_profile="Felipe2")
```

The idea is to dynamically create one class method (like **notify_fan_mail**) for each feed type. It works almost great, the only problem is that the **print** statement always prints "notifying new_event", regardless of the method I call (same for **notify_new_mail**, **notify_review**, etc.).

I realize it's because it's using the last value assigned to type. My question is: how can I dynamically create methods that would use the correct value for **type**?

Also, if I have this exact code in a Python file, is that the correct way to add methods to the Feed class, or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a closure to preserve the value of `kind`:

```
for type_tuple in FEED_TYPES:
    kind, name = type_tuple
    def make_notify(kind):
        def notify(self, **kwargs):
            print "notifying %s" % kind
            self.create(kind, **kwargs)
        return notify
    notify = make_notify(kind)
    notify.__name__ = "notify_%s" % kind
    setattr(cls, notify.__name__, classmethod(notify))
```

By the way, don't use `type` as a variable name since it shadows the builtin of the same name.

---

A more elegant way to modify `Feed` is to create a class decorator. This makes it clearer that you have code modifying the original definition of `Feed`.

```
FEED_TYPES = [
    ('fan_mail',     'Fan Mail'),
    ('review',       'Review'),
    ('tip',          'Tip'),
    ('fan_user',     'Fan User'),
    ('fan_song',     'Fan Song'),
    ('fan_album',    'Fan Album'),
    ('played_song',  'Played Song'),
    ('played_album', 'Played Album'),
    ('played_radio', 'Played Radio'),
    ('new_event',    'New Event'),
]

def add_feed_types(cls):
    for type_tuple in FEED_TYPES:
        kind, name = type_tuple
        def make_notify(kind):
            def notify(self, **kwargs):
                print "notifying %s" % kind
                self.create(kind, **kwargs)
            return notify
        notify = make_notify(kind)
        notify.__name__ = "notify_%s" % kind
        setattr(cls, notify.__name__, classmethod(notify))
    return cls

@add_feed_types
class Feed:
    @classmethod
    def do_create(cls, **kwargs):
        print kwargs

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, kind, **kwargs):
        kwargs['feed_type'] = kind
        cls.do_create(**kwargs)


Feed.create("FanMail", to_profile="Gerson", from_profile="Felipe")
Feed.notify_fan_mail(to_profile="Gerson2", from_profile="Felipe2")
```

Comment: Thank you! The lines `notify = make_notify(typ)` and `notify.__name__ = "notify_%s" % typ` should use `type` (instead of `typ`), correct?

Comment: Oops, `self.create(type, ...)` should be `self.create(typ, ...)`. Everywhere you wrote `type`, I suggest use something different, maybe `kind` instead -- to completely distinguish it from the Python builtin.

Comment: Love the class decorator concept!

Answer (score 1):

The bug is caused by the nature of closures in Python.  The name `type` in your notify functions is bound to `type` in the enclosing scope.  When you change `type`'s value it changes for all closures referring to it.

One way to solve this is use a function factory:

```
def make_notify_function(type):
    def notify(self, **kwargs):
        print "notifying %s" % type
        self.create(type, **kwargs)
    return notify
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into is that your `notify` function isn't encapsulating the value `type`, just it's name. So when your for loop goes onto the next tuple, the old one is lost.

You can fix this by making `type` a default argument to the function:

```
for type, name in FEED_TYPES: # no need to unpack the tuple separately
    def notify(cls, type=type, **kwargs): # type is an argument and default value
        print "notyfying %s" % type
        cls.create(type, **kwargs)

    ...
```

Note that I've changed the `self` argument to `cls`, which is probably more correct, since you're making it a class method.

I think this is an appropriate way to go to add methods to a class at runtime. I'm not sure if that's necessarily something that you need to be doing, but without more information about your task (for instance, what does `do_create` do?) I don't see any other obvious improvements.

Comment: I think this fails if the function is called with more than one positional argument or a named argument called 'type'.